# Topological approach to create a space between clouds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

I have a dataset associated with labels. According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03426.pdf --> [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap)  (Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection) which is a novel manifold learning technique for dimension reduction and the data, I succeeded to create the green and red clouds bellow. The problem I have is they are stick together. For machine learning purposes, it is kinda hard to learn something when the clouds are placed that way.

[image: Cloud 1]

[image: Cloud 2]

Is there a topological approach that might be used to create a significant space between clouds?

**UPDATE**

I would be interested by an analytic approach to separated the two clouds. Each cloud can be seen as a compact space.

Here is an example in 2-D. I would like a way to generalize that concept in z-D, where z would be a finite positive integer.

[image: Clouds separated]

I want to create an algo which will be used with high-frequency speed. So the algo needs to be fast enough. I believe the "Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection" to be tweakable so that I can preprocess the data and pass it to an LSTM. The idea are is three steps : 1- Reduce the dimensionality, separated the clouds and then pass the data to a LSTM model.

**UPDATE 2**

I am trying an approach, but I am far from certain that it's the best solution.

1. Cover each cloud by the smallest possible sphere.
2. Extend the intersection of the spheres by an hyperplane.
3. Taking away the clouds according to the orthogonal vector to the hyperplane by a distance alpha. alpha might be the furthest point on the orthogonal line inside the intersection of the spheres.

Comment: Before applying novel techniques, have you tried simpler methods such as SVM or SVM+kernel?

Comment: I am looking for an analytics technique because I tried many things so far, i.e. PCA, T-SNE, SVC, UMAP (worked better), using neural network to classified the points. I want a technique that can allow me once I apply UMAP to detach what is stuck together. The next step is really to force separating the clouds with a spectral geometry technique probably.

Comment: What does 2. mean? And also, if you know which point is red and which is green then I don't see where is a problem. Whereas if you don't know that, I don't see how anything could be done to separate them.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The point 2 means that if I take the intersection of the spheres, then I am sure we can form an hyperplane according to that intersection. Suppose  $V = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $W = \{w_1, w_2, ..., w_m\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose now the smallest sphere covering $V$ and $W$ by $S(V)$ and $S(W)$. I am sure that $S(V) \cap S(W) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. We just have to define the hyperplane $\mathbb{H} \supset S(V) \cap S(W)$ to define the appropriate orthogonal vector.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yeah, I know in advance the labels. What did you have in mind by "I don't see where is the problem"?

Comment: What I don't understand is why do you need orthogonality or anything like it. Why not, say, add to the z coordinate of each red point one and the same very large number? In other words, what are your constraints?

Comment: The data generated by the transformation will be used to train a machine learning model. I think applying a huge shifting can reduce the accuracy of the model. The changes need to be subtle.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The question has nothing to do with UMAP. I could've remove the UMAP part and asking the same question without loss of generality

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, calculate the diameter of one of the clouds then translate it?

Comment: Oh I think I see now. You need dimensional reduction, right? Both clouds are actually contained in a thin layer, and if you shift just slightly in a carefully chosen direction they become separated?

Comment: @davegaut If you're building features for a model to predict your labels, be very careful about using the labels to make decisions: this can cause signal to leak into your model, and you won't be able to build these features if you're applying the model to a situation where the labels are unknown.